# Stereographic projection of a sphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, projective-geometry, spherical-geometry

What should have been a simple exercise in geometry has morphed into a multi-day affair with me figuratively tearing my hair out. I have no clue what's wrong.

This image accompanies the problem:
[image]

The problem is "simply" to show that
$$r=\frac{\rho}{1+\frac{\rho^2}{4L^2}}$$
I can do the calculus and differential geometry that follows, but I *cannot* figure this out. I've even resorted to getting out a ruler and measuring the relevant quantities to check the answer.

Taking this head-on has done nothing, so I tried to reverse engineer the solution. Calling the large hypotenuse $x$, we have
$$\rho^2+4L^2=x^2$$ 
Inserting this in the answer, we have
$$r=\frac{4L^2\rho}{x^2}$$
I think this is about all that I've been able to to productively.

A huge thank you to anyone who helps in any capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem involving similar triangles.  Can you see the related ratios:
$$\frac{L-\sqrt{L^2-r^2}}{r}=\frac{2 L}{\rho }?$$

Comment: I'd been calling $L-\sqrt{L^2-r^2}$ $b$ the whole time. I knew there was a really simple solution. You have my gratitude.